# How to disable popover when hovered over another card in react js

Tags: reactjs, hover, popover

I'm trying to build course cards in which when hovered to any course card a popover should appear and popover is visible till when i hover on card and popover itself. And when I hover over to next card previous popover should be removed and current hovered card popover should appear.But when hover over another card previous pop over still exist.
[image]

Used package called react-tiny-popover [react-tiny-popover](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tiny-popover)

Below is the code snippet

```
<Popover
  isOpen={isPopoverOpen}
  positions={['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom']}
  padding={10}
  align="center"
  width={200}
  onClickOutside={() => setIsPopoverOpen(false)}
  reposition="true"
  content={({ position, childRect, popoverRect }) => (
    <ArrowContainer // if you'd like an arrow, you can import the ArrowContainer!
      position={position}
      childRect={childRect}
      popoverRect={popoverRect}
      arrowColor={'white'}
      arrowSize={10}
      arrowStyle={{ opacity: 0.7 }}
      className='popover-arrow-container'
      arrowClassName='popover-arrow'
    >
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: '#170055', padding: '10px', borderRadius: '5px', width: '300px', height: '400px', lineHeight: '1.5' }}
        onClick={() => setIsPopoverOpen(!isPopoverOpen)}
      >
        <div class="popover-text">
          <h1 style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
          <h2 style={{ fontSize: '14px' }} class="course-instructor">Dr. Murthy</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vehicula rhoncus metus non condimentum. Int</p>
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vehicula rhoncus metus non condimentum. Int</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vehicula rhoncus metus non condimentum. Int</li>
          </ol>
          <button className="course-button">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ArrowContainer>
    )}
    >
      <div class="tile" onMouseOver={() => setIsPopoverOpen(!isPopoverOpen)} >
        <Link to={props.page}>
          <img src='../../assets/images/courses-01.jpg' alt="ssd" />
          <div class="text">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
            <h2 class="course-instructor">Dr. Murthy</h2>
            <p className="course-price">Rs. 400</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
</Popover>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
onMouseLeave={() => setIsPopoverOpen(false)}
```

for `div class="tile"`